# Why dimension of W is atmost n?

Tags: linear-algebra

i know that this  question has been already but some confusion about this Question [Problem related to the dimension of the vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253076/problem-related-to-the-dimension-of-the-vector-space)

> Let $C$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix. Let $W$ be the vector space
>   spanned by $\{1,C,C^2,\ldots,C^{2n}\}$.

Then, which of the following about the dimension of the vector space W is/are correct?

The dimension of $W$ is:

1. $2n$
2. at most $n$
3. $n^2$
4. at most $2n$.

My attempts :[image]

Its shown clearly from my answer as option 4 is correct  ..that is dimension of W is at most 2n.  my confusion is that Why  option 2 is correct ? why dimension of W is at most n?  pliz   help me , i would be more thankful.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caley hamilton theorem says that every matrix satisfies its charachteristic polynomial. The charachteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ matrix has degree (at most) $n$. So your first equation is wrong, since you go up to degree $2n$.

The proof though is essentially the same; if you write down the charachteristic polynomial correctly (of degree $n$) and repeat the same step as in your proof, then you show that the dimension is at most $n$

Comment: @ Ant im not getting,,,,acording to question it has given that {1,C,,,,,C^2n}...here 2n is the last power  ..so i write it . Can u elaborate why  my first equation is wrong..

Comment: @lomberlego You were given a set. The Cayley-hamilton theorem does not speak of a set, it speak of the charachteristic polynomial of a matrix. You can forget the set to write down the first equation, all you need to prove is that any power of the matrix $C^k$ with $k \ge n$ is a linear combination of smaller powers. This is always true and of course independent on any set I can give you. Then you use this fact to prove that, in particular, the span of $\{1, \dots, C^{2n}\}$ is equal to the span of $\{1, \dots, C^{n-1}\}$ which means that the dimension of the space is at most $n$

Comment: thanks a lots @Ant,,